# Write text to a google doc file with google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to write some text into a new google doc file using the [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client).

I think the following should work, but it doesn't:

```
file_metadata = {
  name: "Testing",
  mime_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}

@drive.create_file(file_metadata,
                   fields: 'id',
                   upload_source: StringIO.new("tt"),
                   content_type: 'text/text')
```

When I run this I get `Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: Bad Request`

---

UPDATE: After Tanaike posted the correct answer below, I also had to move the file as it was created in the root directory of my service user. The final (working) code looks like this

```
file_metadata = {
  name: "Filename",
  mime_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}

file = @drive.create_file(file_metadata,
                   fields: 'id,parents',
                   upload_source: StringIO.new("Text to go in file"),
                   content_type: 'text/plain')

current_parent = file.parents.first
@drive.update_file(file.id, nil,
                   add_parents: "#{@folder_id}",
                   remove_parents: "#{current_parent}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? In this case, the mimeType of text is `text/plain`.

#### From:

```
content_type: 'text/text'
```

#### To:

```
content_type: 'text/plain'
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, when I use `content_type: 'text/text'`, the same error occurs. And when I use `content_type: 'text/plain'`, the Google Document including the text of `tt` is created to the root folder on Google Drive.
- In this case, it supposes that your `@drive` can be used for uploading a file.

#### Reference:

- [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)